# How to upload lots of image files by URL?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

So I need to display lots and lots of images in my tableview. Since I'm using Parse, it provides a class called PFImageView which can help you load and cache remote images easily. But to use that function, I need to get my photos to upload to Parse first, but since I only got the URLs of these images (approximately 4000 pictures), so I can't use PFFile to do that(because it can only upload images what are already on your hard disc). So anyway that i can do that? Thanks everyone for helping me!
   By the way, I'm using Swift 2.0 and Xcode 7 to develop my app.

Comment: Since you need to get the images from the URLs, you could either get them client-side on the app and upload them or use a cloud code function to fetch and save them. The implementation will vary depending on how you are storing the URLs

Comment: So I'm trying to 'get them client-side on the app and upload them', any idea?

Comment: It really depends on how the URLs are stored. Do you have them in a CSV file on your machine? Are they being scraped from a website? It's impossible to help without knowing the details